# How to add spaces before & after a set of expressions using re.sub() in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How to add spaces before & after a set of expressions showing below:
"-", "_", "abc", "%dKK" (%d means an integer here)

For example, "abc3KK-_" will be split as " abc 3KK - _ ".

Thanks.

Comment: Why must we use `re.sub()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you could do something like `re.sub('abc\B', 'abc ', your_string)` for each expression

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I just want to learn the syntax but if you have a better solution than re.sub(), it helps as well. Thanks.

Comment: @ryugie Can we address the four expressions at the same time using re.sub()? Besides, what about the '%dKK' one? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`' '.join(re.findall('-|_|abc|\d+KK', 'abc3KK-_'))` would work for your example.

It does not use `re.sub` but still uses a regex.

Since there is not much information about the kind of strings you want to handle, I don't know if it fits your needs.